# How to handle external dependencies in perl's ExtUtils:MakeMaker

Tags: perl, makefile, dependencies, external

I have a series of perl scripts for which I'm writing a `Makefile.PL` script, but I'm rather inexperienced with [`ExtUtils::MakeMaker`](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils%3a%3aMakeMaker).

One of the scripts I wrote makes a system call to a command line utility that must be installed in order for the script to run properly.  My script can gracefully detect that the utility is missing and issue an error about installing it and putting it in the user's path, but is there some standard way to handle this in the Makefile.PL script?  Could it even *gasp* attempt to install the third-party utility if I enter the download link in the Makefile.PL script?

At the very least, I'd like the script to warn the user if the external dependency was not found.  I know I can write a test case that uses it.  Is this as simple as copying and pasting the subroutine I wrote in the script itself that checks for the third party utility and prints an error if it's not found or would that be the "wrong way to do it"?

Comment: what is the utility you need? As perl is platform independent then it needs to have the utility on all platforms if you are planning to add it to CPAN. On the other hand, there might be a perl implementation of the utility already which you can then add as a module dependency

Comment: The utility is a command-line utility and it has binaries for most systems.  It's a multiple sequence aligner for DNA & protein sequences called muscle (http://www.drive5.com/muscle/downloads.htm).  I call it from within my script using IPC::Open3.  Without knowing if there's a standard way of checking for such a command-line dependency, I simply created a sub in Makefile.PL that checks for it and issues a warning if it's not in the user's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an external dependency on a command-line utility (i.e. there's no perl module that does what the utility does), ExtUtils::MakeMaker is not designed to handle such a dependency.  What you need to do is write an install script or edit the make file to handle the dependency.  Here are the considerations in doing so:

1. Check if the dependency exists and if the version is sufficient.
2. Download the dependent package
3. Configure, compile, & install the dependent package
4. Test to make sure it works
5. Update the user's environment setup if necessary
6. Run your perl package's installation steps (e.g. perl makefile.PL;make;sudo make install)

Note, you may need to know whether your script is running as root or not, which you can verify using `id -u` to check if the user ID is root (i.e. '0').

Comment: BTW, I submitted this answer since no one else has offered a solution.  This is basically how I ended up doing it and it works well on multiple systems, though each system had some quirks to overcome. I didn't go into much detail. If anyone offers a better solution, I will switch the preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call this external dependency `foobar`, for sake of argument.

As per @KeepCalmAndCarryOn's comment, firstly consider whether `foobar` could be replaced by something from CPAN (maybe `Foo::Bar`), or a few lines of Perl.

Otherwise, the best course of action is:

1. Create a new CPAN distribution called `Alien::Foobar`. The job of `Alien::Foobar` is to download, perhaps compile, and then install `foobar`, as part of `Alien::Foobar`'s Makefile.PL or Build.PL.

   (There exists a module called [`Alien::Base`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::Base) which aims to make doing this sort of thing easier. It's mostly aimed at installing libraries rather than binaries, though I've had some success using it for the latter.)
2. Now the Makefile.PL you were originally working on can declare a dependency on `Alien::Foobar`.

Comment: So is there no conventional way for handling 3rd party command line executable dependencies? I just finished writing a shell install script that handles the dependency install. Essentially, it's just a curl, tar, chmod, cp, & ln; but I need to worry about where they want it installed, whether it's being installed as root, whether those commands are present, append to the user's environment scripts, etc.. This is my first ever attempt at such a script. Is there an easier way to do it?